# Tableview content data

Tags: uitableview, swift2, uitextfield

I have tableview inside view controller. 
At the bottom there is a textfield and when user click it textfield move up with keyboard. and also tableview move too.

If i have small (just 2-3 line) data in tableview when textfield move up then I can not see my data until keyboard disappear.

I tried to change tableview contentinset values but it did not work for me.

This is my code when move up the my textfield area.

```
if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
                tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardSize.height, 0)
                self.messageView.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
```

I think I lose my data because I also move up to view too. But I Can not find any solution.

How can I see the data? How can I fix my problem?

Thanks